# Algorithm Problem: Word transformation from a given word to another using only the words in a given dict

Tags: algorithm, graph

The detailed description of the problem is as follows:

Given two words (beginWord and endWord), and a dictionary's word list, find if there's a transformation sequence from beginWord to endWord, such that:

1. Only one letter can be changed at a time
2. Each transformed word must exist in the word list. Note that beginWord is not a transformed word.

I know this word can be solved using breadth-first-search. After I proposed the normal BFS solution, the interviewer asked me if I can make it faster. I didn't figure out a way to speed up. And the interviewer told me I should use a PriorityQueue instead to do a "Best-First-Search". And the priority is given by the hamming distance between the current word and target.

I don't quite understand why this can speed up the search. I feel by using priorityQueue we try to search the path that makes progress (i.e. reducing hamming distance).

This seems to be a greedy method. My questions is:

Why this solution is faster than the breadth-first-search solution? I feel the actual path can be like this: at first not making any progress, or even increasing the hamming distance, but after reaching a word the hamming distance goes down gradually. In this scenario, I think the priority queue solution will be slower.

Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: That's very similar to comparing Dijkstra's algorithm with A*. It is still potentially exploring all possibilities, but taking the most promising first.

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the reply. I still didn't quite get that. Why it's similar to comparing Dijkstra's algorithm with A*? I feel Dijkstra is already optimal. Is A* even faster than that? I think what confuses me is this: if we also want to find the min number of steps to reach dst, can we still use the priority queue solution? I'm confused because I feel breadth-first-search already gives the best performance.

Comment: Well, the difference is between an algorithm that is "blind" and searches in all directions until it stumbles over the solution to one that has some notion where the goal is and tries the ways in the direction to the goal first. The latter approach is usually better and apart from some bookkeeping effort never worse.

Comment: I think the priorithqueue way does not speed up the algorithm in a fundamental way, but just increase the `possibility`

Comment: It just has a higher possibility of get the answer faster in a single time, but no grantee. I think if this algorithm will be excuteb many times, it will be speeded up.

Comment: A* is an opportunistic optimization. The real optimization (which the interviewer apparently also missed) is to run simultaneous BFSs from both ends, until they meet halfway. If the distance is `d`, and an average branch factor is `f` the single BFS would explore `k**d` nodes, while the two BFSs would only explore `2 * k**(d/2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd recommend to do some thorough reading on graph searching algorithms, that will explain the question to any detail you want (and far beyond).

TL;DR:

Your interviewer effectively recommended something close to the A* algorithm.

It differs from BFS in one aspect: which node to expand first. It uses a notion of distance score, composed from two elements:

- At a node X, we already "traveled" a distance given by the number of transformations so far.
- To reach the target from X, we still need to travel some more, at least N steps, where N is the number of characters different between node and target.

If we are to follow the path through X, the total number of steps from start to target can't be less than this score. It can be more if the real rest distance turns out to be longer (some words necessary for the direct path don't exist in the dictionary).

A* tells us: of all open (unexpanded) nodes, try the one first that potentially gives the shortest overall solution path, i.e. the one with the lowest score. And to implement that, a priority queue is a good fit.

In many cases, A* can dramatically reduce the search space (compared to BFS), and it still guarantees to find the best solution.

A* is NOT a greedy algorithm. It will eventually explore the whole search space, only in a much better ordering than a blind BFS.